# Vim + Syntastic: "Unclosed regular expression" for JSX

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write a React native app (which uses JSX) but my  keeps complaining that my syntax is wrong even when it isn't.

This is what I see:

[image]

When I run `:SyntasticInfo` I see this:

[image]

In my `.vimrc` file I have this line
`let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eshint', 'jsxhint', 'jshint']` so I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Syntax is ok, but JSHint is may be recognizing the `/Provider` line as a RegExp, which is not valid from a non-JSX point of view.